# Screen socket not generating

Tags: python, flask, minecraft

I'm making a python flask server to run and turn off multiple Minecraft servers, Im using screen to run the minecraft server however screen seems to ignore my command

```
@app.route('/startserver/<int:serverid>', methods=['PUT'])
def start(serverid):
    os.system(
        f'screen -dmS {serverid} java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui')

    return("Server starting")
```

When I preform the `screen -ls` command it doesn't always show up.
I tried it without the python and just entered it in the terminal but it still didnt work.

Im running mac os and I intend to later move it to production on a linux server.

Comment: Does the command `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui` works well or it has an error while starting ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. That was the problem, the server jar file was not found because it was in a different directory therefore the `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui` failed

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I suggested you to self-answer or just delete your question, as you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Elikill58 kindly suggested that the command that I started with might of failed. Which is what happened. When I ensured the `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui` worked properly the screen socket consistently generated.